# How to forward a Docker bridge network port to localhost

Tags: docker, docker-network

I am using Docker Desktop on Windows with the WSL 2 based engine. I have a container on a bridge network, with a port published on that network, such that it may communicate with another container on the same bridge network. I would like to be able to access that port from my localhost (on Windows).

I created the bridge network using:

```
docker network create my-network
```

I ran the first container whose port (8050) I would like to access using:

```
docker run --interactive -p 8050:8050 --net my-network my-image
```

after including `EXPOSE 8050` in it's image's Dockerfile.

Here, port 8050 is that of a Dash app running on the container whose dashboard I would like to be able to access in-browser on Windows.

Comment: If your app is listening on port 8050 and is bound to 0.0.0.0, you should be able to reach it on `http://localhost:8050/` from the Windows host. Your Docker setup looks correct.